# Laravel 7.x Sanctum (SPA) with Vuejs always returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

So it's been several hours I couldn't figure out the issue even reading through and trying any possible solution available on the internet. I'm using **Laravel 7.x** with **Vue js** and struggling with **Sanctum SPA** authentication.

**Login** request works fine which is using **Auth::routes()** defined in *web.php*

[image]

**but,** any requests made to APIs defined in **api.php** under **auth:sanctum middleware** returns 401. For example, call to fetch the user object fails with status 401:

[image]

Here is the **Request Header:**

[image]

This is **web.php**

[image]

This is **api.php**

[image]

Here is the **stateful** object in **sanctum.php**

`'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000')),`

On vue.js side, I've set the withCredentials flag to true:

`window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`

`window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

in **cors.php**, suports_credentials flag is also set to true

[image]

and, here is my **Kernel.php**

```
/**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: what is the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` and why is it in the Kernel file namespace ? Since you want statefull sessions, why not use the `web` group instead of the `api` one ? if it is juste for the prefix `/api` in the url, you can change that even using `web` group.

Comment: I'm following the Laravel documentation for Sanctum SPA authentication. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-configuration

Comment: did you find a solution? I followed the instructions stated in laravel.com/docs/7.x   but the instruction they given was limited.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and I couldn't find any answer but after troubleshooting I got it working.

Your issue is that you're accessing it through `localhost` port 8000, but in your stateful param under sanctum config there is no `localhost:8000` (even `localhost` pointing to `127.0.0.1`). The config uses `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` so it actually looks for the exact content while accessing it.

A simple fix below:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', implode(',', [
    'localhost',
    'localhost:8000',
]))),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Icaro. This had me scratching my head whole day. Such a silly thing, but I think it should be mentioned somewhere in official docs too.

Comment: Icaro has the answer, however, you should add it to your .env file as
`SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="localhost:8000"`
Instead of the `sanctum.php` file

Comment: @aseladaskon can you elaborate which package versions, urls/ips are you using?

Comment: hello Ícaro R. Scherma, I decided to skip this authentication package. I'm using spatie package.

Answer (score -2):

I not use Sanctum but use Vuejs Laravel and Axios and I notice that you need to add to all axios protected URL the header Authorization

Bearer YOURTOKENKEY

On my ap.js I use

```
import jwtToken from './helpers/jwt-token'

    axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        config.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken
        config.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

        if (jwtToken.getToken()) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jwtToken.getToken()
        }

        return config;
    }, error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

and my JWTTOKEN js file

```
export default {
    setToken(token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('jwt_token', token);
    },
    getToken() {
        return window.localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
    },
}
```

So all request by axios send Authorization  header with Bearer + token

I hope this help you

Comment: It's a stateful session way and X-CRF-TOKEN is automatically sent. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-configuration