Logout functionality gives 401 unauthorized error. I'm using Vue Js with Capacitor Js Storage and Laravel API with sanctum token
I'm new to vue js and I have been trying to fix this for a week. Using postman the logout functionality works correctly but when I hit logout from frontend the user session is logged out from the front end but console has the error 401 unauthorized and token in the database isn't deleted.
Exact error

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout 401 (Unauthorized) useApi.js:44

useApi.js (Composable)
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { SecureStoragePlugin } from "capacitor-secure-storage-plugin";

export default function useApi() {
  const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"; // Update with your API URL
  const data = ref([]);
  const errors = ref("");

  // Method for fetching data
  const getData = async (endpoint) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/${endpoint}`);
      data.value = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      errors.value = "Failed to fetch data";
    }
  };

  // Method for posting data
  const postData = async (endpoint, payload) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/${endpoint}`, payload);
      data.value.push(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      errors.value = "Failed to post data";
    }
  };

  // Method for user login
  const login = async (credentials) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/login`, credentials);
      data.value = response.data; // Assuming the response contains user data or a token
    } catch (error) {
      errors.value = error.response.data.message || "Failed to login";
    }
  };

  // Method for user logout
  const logout = async (token) => {
    try {
      console.log(token);
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${apiUrl}/logout`,
        {},
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      // Assuming the response contains a success message or status
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      errors.value = error.response.data.message || "Failed to logout";
    }
  };

  // Method for user registration
  const register = async (userData) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/register`, userData);
      data.value = response.data; // Assuming the response contains user data or a confirmation message
    } catch (error) {
      errors.value = error.response.data.message || "Failed to register";
    }
  };

  // Add more methods as needed for PUT, DELETE, etc.

  return { data, errors, getData, postData, login, register, logout };
}


MyAccount.vue (Where logout logic is triggered)
<template>
  <k-page>
    <k-navbar title="My Account" class="justify-center font-bold">
      <template #left>
        <k-link navbar @click="() => toggleMenu()"> Menu </k-link>
      </template>
    </k-navbar>
    <button
      class="font-bold bg-red-500 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-lg"
      @click="handleLogout">
      Logout
    </button>
    <main-footer></main-footer>
    <nav-menu></nav-menu>
  </k-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import { kPage, kNavbar, kLink } from "konsta/vue";
import MainFooter from "@/components/MainFooter.vue";
import NavMenu from "@/components/NavMenu.vue";
import { useMainMenu } from "../composables/useMainMenu";
const { toggleMenu } = useMainMenu();

import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { SecureStoragePlugin } from "capacitor-secure-storage-plugin";
import useApi from "../composables/useApi";

const router = useRouter();
const { logout } = useApi();

async function handleLogout() {
  try {
    // Attempt to retrieve the token from secure storage
    const token = await SecureStoragePlugin.get({ key: "authToken" });
    if (!token) {
      // If the token is not found, redirect to the login page
      router.push("/login");
      return; // Exit the function early
    }

    await logout(token);
    // Remove the token from secure storage
    await SecureStoragePlugin.remove({ key: "authToken" });
    // Redirect the user to the login page
    router.push("/login");
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the error
    console.error("Logout error:", error);
    // Optionally, display an error message to the user
    // For example, using a toast notification or a modal
    // This is a placeholder for your error handling logic
    // You might want to use a UI library or framework feature to display the error
    // For instance, if you're using Vue 3 with the Composition API, you could use a reactive state to trigger a UI component
    // that displays the error message
  }
}
</script>


I don't know if it's needed as postman requests work but here is the laravel controller for the logout.
Laravel AuthController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'usertype' => 'customer',
        ]);

        // Optionally, return the user with a token or a message
        return response()->json(['user' => $user], 201);
    }


    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
        }

        try {
            $user->tokens()->delete();

            return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->plainTextToken,
                'status' => 'success',
                'message'=> 'User logged in successfully',
                'name' => $user->name,
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }




    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            // Attempt to revoke the user's token
            $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

            // Return a success response
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'message' => 'User logged out successfully'
                ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid token'], 401);
        }
    }
}

And here is the api.php routes file (edited).
api.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get('/auth/google', [AuthController::class, 'handleGoogleLogin']);
Route::get('/auth/google/call-back', [AuthController::class, 'googleLogin']);

Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name("register");
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name("login");

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name("logout");


What did I try.

Changing axios to fetch call gives 405 method not allowed error and doesn't logout the frontend session unlike axios which did logout but gave 401. This is what I changed in the useApi for fetch.
const logout = async (token) => {
  try {
    console.log(token);

    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/logout`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
      }
    });

    if(!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }

    return response.json();

  } catch (error) {
    errors.value = error.message || "Failed to logout";
    throw error;
  }
}


Changing Post to Delete in the front and not in the backend api routes gives 405 method not allowed and changing both back and frontend to delete method gives 401 unauthorized again. Works same (logs out but doesn't delete token in the backend.)

Console the token before logout functionality gives the same token as it was generated.



Can you show your routes (php artisan route:list)or api.php route file?

@Henridv I edited above and added api.php please check it out.

Check if you have instructed Sanctum to make your api endpoints stateful: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#sanctum-middleware. Or https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#installation if you're on Laravel 10.

Does removing the try-catch from your logout action returns the error trace as the response so you can debug from there? If so, you might want to post that trace too

The error is coming from the server side can you please dd() the request and look in the browser by dev tools at network tab what the response of the server is?

Your solution is in the first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354802/laravel-7-x-sanctum-spa-with-vuejs-always-returns-401-unauthorized

@DanieleAlessandra what about if I am using a virtualhost? I am using the url of it and I'm having the same error
